# Can't get the javascript to emulate a post

Tags: javascript, php, post, submit

I have the following javascript

```
function submitform(formid)
{
   document.forms[formid].submit();
}

function submitform_with_value(eleid,ipvalue,formid)
{
   var ele = document.getElementById(eleid);
   ele.value = ipvalue;
   submitform(formid);
}
```

and I call it from an onchange event so

```
submitform_with_value("upload","upload","frmupphoto")
```

the input's id is '`upload`' the form id is '`frmupphoto`', and I am expecting the value upload in the post.  Everything works execpt that the `$_POST` in php is null. `$_FILES` has the file details.

What do I have to do to get something in the post ?

Comment: have you set **method="post"**  for your form?

Comment: Yes the method is set to post.

Comment: Ok! just make sure **ele** has name rather than id.

Comment: what?! is this a test?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour, sorry, that was not aimed at you.  I had a serial downvoter on my tail.  He has stopped now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured that you can not simulate a post by doing a submit.  So I am clicking the button instead, which triggers a post.  And it does what I want.

```
onchange='document.frmupphoto.upload.click();'
```

What I was trying to do was to post the form as soon as the file selection window is closed.  The above is the onchange for the " input type=file "

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things here:

1. Your $_FILES variable is being populated because you most likely have your form "enctype" attribute set to "multipart/form-data" - which is primarily used for file uploads.
2. The $_POST variable gets populated by an input field's "name" attribute, not "id".

Comment: 1.  Correct as I do want a file.  2.  To keep it simple the name is the same as the id.  I am using the id to find the element as it will be unique.